# How to collapse vertical space around grid items?

Tags: css, css-grid

With a screen size > 576px and without changing the HTML, how can I collapse the divs so that the divs in the right-hand column appear below each other with only a 10px grid-row-gap.

The description, features and tick-features divs all have dynamic content.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
}
.container h1, .container div {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.container h1 {
  background: blue;
}
.container .description {
  background: darkslategray;
}
.container .features {
  background: green;
}
.container .tick-features {
  background: purple;
}
.container .static-map {
  background: maroon;
}
.container .full-width {
  background: darkolivegreen;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    max-width: 700px;
  }
  .container h1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }
  .container .description {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/5;
    height: 500px;
  }
  .container .features {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .container .tick-features {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .container .static-map {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }
  .container .full-width {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
  <div class="features">Features</div>
  <div class="description">Description</div>
  <div class="tick-features">Tick features</div>
  <div class="static-map">Static Map</div>
  <div class="full-width">Full width div</div>
</div>
```

Adding images to show what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Image 1 - long description]

+++

[image: Image 2 - short description - long features]

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

It's important to note that the cells in the right-hand column are already next to each other, separated only by the 10px row gap.

[image]

As you can see with the dashed outlines, there is no wide vertical gap between the cells on the right. The are right next to each other.

The problem is that each item within the cell has a lower height than the row it's in.

```
  .container .features {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .container .tick-features {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

With each item set to `height: 100px`, it doesn't cover the full height of the cell, leaving a lot of empty space.

---

### Solutions

Depending on what exactly you need, you can approach the problem in various ways. Here are two:

### 1. Use `min-height` instead of `height`

Replace `height: 100px` with `min-height: 100px`, allowing the items to consume all free space. (Consider a similar switch for the `.description` item.)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
}

.container h1,
.container div {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container h1 {
  background: blue;
}

.container .description {
  background: darkslategray;
}

.container .features {
  background: green;
}

.container .tick-features {
  background: purple;
}

.container .static-map {
  background: maroon;
}

.container .full-width {
  background: darkolivegreen;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .container h1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }

  .container .description {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/5;
    /* height: 500px; */
    min-height: 500px; /* new */
  }

  .container .features {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    /* height: 100px; */
    min-height: 100px; /* new */
  }

  .container .tick-features {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    /* height: 100px; */
    min-height: 100px; /* new */    
  }

  .container .static-map {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }

  .container .full-width {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
  <div class="features">Features</div>
  <div class="description">Description</div>
  <div class="tick-features">Tick features</div>
  <div class="static-map">Static Map</div>
  <div class="full-width">Full width div</div>
</div>
```

### 2. Use `grid-template-rows`

You may also be able to handle the problem at the container level, using `grid-template-rows`.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
}

.container h1,
.container div {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.container h1 {
  background: blue;
}

.container .description {
  background: darkslategray;
}

.container .features {
  background: green;
}

.container .tick-features {
  background: purple;
}

.container .static-map {
  background: maroon;
}

.container .full-width {
  background: darkolivegreen;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 50% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:  50px minmax(100px, 1fr) minmax(100px, 1fr) 100px 50px;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .container h1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }

  .container .description {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/5;
    /* height: 500px; */
  }

  .container .features {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    /* height: 100px */
  }

  .container .tick-features {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    /* height: 100px; */
  }

  .container .static-map {
    grid-column: 2 /3;
    grid-row: 4 / 5;
  }

  .container .full-width {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 5 / 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
  <div class="features">Features</div>
  <div class="description">Description</div>
  <div class="tick-features">Tick features</div>
  <div class="static-map">Static Map</div>
  <div class="full-width">Full width div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added a couple of images to show what I'm trying to achieve. I think it may only be possible by wrapping the right-hand items in a div?